# InfoBar with enabled message text selection

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, styling, winui-3, winui

Is it possible to somehow set the `IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"` property of the WinUI 3 InfoBar's message without copying the whole control template from [source](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/InfoBar/InfoBar.xaml)?

I've tried without success some setters, or using ContentTemplate to add a custom TextBlock, but that causes the action button to be above the message, which I don't want.

```
<InfoBar x:Name="errorBar" Severity="Error" IsOpen="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Margin="50" Loaded="ErrorBar_Loaded">
    <InfoBar.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Message"
                       Text="{x:Bind}"
                       IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </InfoBar.ContentTemplate>
    <InfoBar.ActionButton>
        <Button Content="Action" Click="InfoBarButton_Click" />
    </InfoBar.ActionButton>
</InfoBar>
```

Comment: If you don't want to bring the entire template, you might be able to use the VisualTreeHelper to access the message ``TextBlock``. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ai-koyvgbWY) might help.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the advice, VisualTreeHelper was where I needed to be guided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to overridD the Xaml, you will need to do it in the Code-behind. Based on the [source code of the InfoBar](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/ba45dbd7f8a28ac9d446ca57eeda2f1397fe4a76/dev/InfoBar/InfoBar.xaml#L175), we could know the name of the TextBlock for message. It is called `Message`. So we could use [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621) to get the TextBlock control from the InfoBar and change its property.

I've made a sample here and you could refer to it:

**MainPage.Cs:**

```
        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Content = "Clicked";

      
       UpdateAvailableNotification.IsOpen = !UpdateAvailableNotification.IsOpen;

        TextBlock textBlock = TryFindChildByName(UpdateAvailableNotification, "Message") as TextBlock;
        textBlock.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
      
    }

    public static DependencyObject TryFindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
                return MyChild;

            var FindResult = TryFindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
            if (FindResult != null)
                return FindResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**MainPage.Xaml:**

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <InfoBar x:Name="UpdateAvailableNotification"
            Title="Update available."
            Message="Restart the application to apply the latest update.">
    </InfoBar>

    <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    
    
</StackPanel>
```

**The result:**

[image]